# Module not found even though it is installed

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I have a poetry project and I have a venv setup. This is my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "..."
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["..."]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
boto3 = "^1.26.78"
requests = "^2.28.2"
black = "^23.1.0"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

After that, I `poetry shell` and `poetry install`.

`poetry show` shows me the following:

> requests           2.28.2    Python HTTP for Humans.
> ...

I am running my project inside Intellij. I already pointed to my poetry venv and when I try to run the project I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

requests could be many different sub-modules so like if you are using urllib request it would be

```
import urllib.request
```

I would recommend urllib.request because it has worked well in the past.
I'm pretty sure "requests" is pretty old and very finicky and difficult to use. i was trying to access data from a server a few days ago so users wouldn't have to redownload in order to get updates and instead run code grabbed from my webserver. I tried getting requests to work but to no avail. after some digging around I found urllib which worked like a charm.

for example, this code grabs code from a webpage and executes it:

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pastebin.com/raw/j5LSmvP4')
r = page.read()
exec(r.decode())
```

also when creating a StackOverflow question, I would recommend showing a code snippet or example as a visual representation to know what the answer-er is dealing with.

Comment: i'm gonna try that :) thanks Westin!

Comment: if it worked, remember to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark and upvoting (if possible)!

Comment: sorry Westin! I actually didn't try. Wanted to keep using `requests` as part of the solution. I'll try a few things more